VF page command button onclick not working
I have a command button("Send") for sending notification on a VF page, when I click the send button , it sends the notification, but the vf page popup doesn't get closed. On clicking the second time on send button the vf page pop up gets closed. In the first click only, it sends the notification using a flow but does not get closed. Below is the syntax:
<apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!submitNotification}" onclick="handleSubmit()"/>

Below is the script I have added in vf page for closing the popup:
<script>
    function handleSubmit() {
        console.log("Test inside handlesubmit1");
        if ({!isNotificationSent}) {
            console.log("Test inside handlesubmit");
            closeLightbox();  // This will close the popup after the notification is sent
            return false;  // Prevent form submission
        }
        return true;  // Continue with form submission

    }
</script>

Can anyone please guide, to resolve this.

I see you've added console.logs in your code - please include screenshots of the browser console as well with any relevant information. Perhaps there is some error showing up there as well?

It's been a long time since I touched this stuff, but unless your script is being re-rendered {!isNotifcationSent} is not going to change. If you do re-render the script it'll update, but I suspect the browser will refuse to run the JS code. You might find it easier to use an actionFunction where you can return a value to the JS to test, or VF remoting.
